# Unable to install Ubuntu 14 in Virtual Box

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ubuntu-14.04

I'm running VirtualBox 5.0.8 in Windows 10 Home and am trying to install 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04.3 as a VM. When I run Ubuntu, it shows the VM splash screen and tries to load, but I get this error:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz9Rx.png]

EDIT: I have tried resetting the VM and enabling "acpi=off" as recommended with no result. I have also tried the various other options in f6.

Comment: Have you turned Hyper-V off? Control Panel - Programs - Windows features and untick Hyper-V.Also which Ubuntu virtualbox are you using and did you load it yourself or download it?

Comment: I can't find Hyper-V in Windows features. I'm using Oracle VM VirtualBox: https://www.virtualbox.org/ . I'm not sure what you mean by loading it myself; I downloaded VirtualBox 5.0.8 from the site, and downloaded and mounted the official Ubuntu ISO from Ubuntu's website. I've tried mounting the 32x and 64x versions of the OS as well.

Comment: getting closer :) Which version of Ubuntu, how much disk space, have you loaded any other software or made changes? re Hyper-V, you can google that but if you type in the search box "Windows Features" and wait a few seconds it will pop up.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.3 with 1gb of ram. I don't remember how much disk space I allocated to it, or how to check that. This OS is the only thing I've loaded in the VirtualBox; no other software or OSs. re Hyper-V, I looked in "Turn Windows features on and off" and since there was no search bar in that window, I searched through every section and didn't find Hyper-V.

Comment: I googled hyper-v, and it's only on Windows Pro, Enterprise, and Education. I have Windows 10 Home. I'll edit the main post with that info.

Comment: Thanks - try loading a pre-cooked Ubuntu image? http://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/

Comment: Ubuntu 14 isn't on that list, and the two most recent versions only have torrents available. Is there an alternative download, or do I need to set myself up to start using torrents?

Comment: If you want Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit then why not install vagrant?  I use the 64bit version for all my software developement. https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty32

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. For now, I'd like to stick to the better documented and more widely supported Ubuntu.

Comment: That is Ubuntu dude :)  Vagrant manages the versions (keeps them up to date), and runs them in virtualbox. Basically the box runs on your computer - to run it go "vagrant up" and to login use "vagrant ssh"

Comment: Ah, I see thanks for the clarification :) Now I'm probably blind, but I can't find a download anywhere on the site.

Answer (score 2):

> reset the VM and after selecting the language just press F6 and press enter to
>   select `acpi=off` then ESC to go back. This should do it.

http://fbinotto.blogspot.com/2012/03/smbus-base-address-uninitialized.html

Comment: I tried this, and then tried the "try ubuntu before installing" and "install ubuntu" options with no success. I still get the same error. Thanks for the quick response, though!